# SherlockNavigationDrawer show listview in main content

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I use ActionBarSherlock with SherlockNavigationDrawer

The default **fragment_main_layout.xml** is

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/content_text"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:text="@string/description"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</ScrollView>
<!-- android:layout_gravity="left" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side. The drawer is
     given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="left"
          android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

I need to put another listview where TextView is displayed. To make myself clear, i need the user to press the navigation drawer, choose an option from the left_drawer and there will be shown a listview in the main content window instead of the textview.

I have done some experiments, however they resulted to conflict with the two listviews (sometimes not populating the left_drawer or the opposite, or showing only the first field from the second listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it myself

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/main_content_list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/content_text"
              android:paddingLeft="5dp"
              android:paddingRight="5dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:text="@string/description"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- android:layout_gravity="left" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side. The drawer is
     given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="left"
          android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

Changed ScrollView to RelativeLayout, added new listview with id:main_content_list inside